# Mapping Uknown/New MongoDB fields to Map/List - Java

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework-2.0

I have a Mongo database and am building a REST API using the Play Framework in Java. I would like to map my Mongo query results to POJOs using some kind of mapper like MongoJack or PlayJongo or something similar.

My problem is that I don't want to have to specify all/new fields in my POJO. What I would like to do is to put all un-mapped fields into a catch all Map as part of the POJO. That way new fields that are added can still be returned in the API response without the Java application having to be aware of them.

Here's an example:

Mongo Document:

```
{
  _id: 1234,
  mappedString: "Foo",
  mappedInt: 544,
  unMappedString: "Test",
  unMappedInt: 12
}
```

Java Class

```
public class Bar {
    private int _id;
    private String mappedString;
    private int mappedInt;

    private Map<String, Object> unMappedFields;
}
```

I would then expect the unMappedFields field to have two entries in it being "unMappedString" and "unMappedInt" with values "Test" and 12 respectively.

Is there a way to achieve this with one of the Mongo POJO mappers? I've not been able to find any information on if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to store in mongo as:

```
{
  _id: 1234,
  mappedString: "Foo",
  mappedInt: 544,
  unMappedFields: 
  {
  unMappedString: "Test",
  unMappedInt: 12
  }
}
```

I have worked with morphia and this case would be directly parsed.

Comment: unfortunately we have a current database that this is being built around, so cannot change the db structure at present.

Comment: So I think you must do your own parser class.